How to create a close button with a black cross and a gray background?
Currently, by using this code.
Button(action: { }) {
    Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
        .imageScale(.large)
        .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.lightGray))
}

My button will have

Transparent color cross mark
Light gray background


However, what if I would like to achieve

Black color cross mark
Light gray background

which looks like

May I know how I can achieve such? Thanks.

Although the 2nd picture you show seems to have a white background, you could try using .foregroundStyle(.black, .gray.opacity(0.2)), adjusting the opacity to your requirement.

Use code like this:
Button(action: {}) {
    Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
        .imageScale(.large)
        .foregroundStyle(.black,.lightGray)
}

Just know that you'll have to define a color called lightGray in your assets file.
Here's an image:

That said, you should really consider using colors that adjust for the display mode (dark or light) and names that match. It's trivial to define alternate colors in the assets file,

Set the modifier symbolRenderingMode to palette and then select the colours you want
 Button(action: { dismiss() }) {
     Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
         .symbolRenderingMode(.palette)
         .imageScale(.large)
         .foregroundStyle(.black, .gray)
}


The other answers show ways of defining the colors for the symbol.
However, you might want to be aware that when button shapes is turned on in the accessibility settings, the button will show the form of a rounded rectangle in the background:


Note that this also makes the button larger.
Since your button already has a distinct shape, you might want to avoid having the additional shape in the background when the accessibility setting is turned on. This can be done by moving the styling to a custom ButtonStyle.
Other points to consider:

You might want to make sure that your button conforms to Apple's accessibility guidelines by giving it a minimum size of 44x44.

Instead of using .black as the foreground color, you could use .primary. This will automatically switch to white when dark mode is enabled.

When pressed, a change in opacity can be used to give a slightly adapted look.


struct MySymbolButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .imageScale(.large)
            .foregroundStyle(.primary, Color(.lightGray))
            .frame(minWidth: 44, minHeight: 44)
            .opacity(configuration.isPressed ? 0.5 : 1)
    }
}

You might like to add a View extension for applying this button style too:
extension View {
    func symbolButtonStyle() -> some View {
        buttonStyle(MySymbolButtonStyle())
    }
}

Now the original code simplifies to the following:
Button {} label: {
    Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
}
.symbolButtonStyle()

This looks the same, even when button shapes is turned on, and automatically switches between white and black foreground for light and dark modes:

